# Why const is ignored when deducing type from universal reference?

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding, type-deduction

Here is the definition of my A class and make function for it:

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
public:
    A( T test )
    : _test( test )
    {}

public:
    const T _test;
};

template <typename T>
A<T> make_a (T&& elem) {
    return A<T>{std::forward<T>(elem)};
}
```

When I pass int lvalue to `make_a` function, I expect the instantiated class to be similar to

```
class B
{
public:
    B( int &test )
    : _test( test )
    {}

public:
    const int &_test;
};
```

But the type of `A::_test` is deduced to be `int&` instead of `const int&`:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int a = 1;
    auto aa = make_a(a);
    aa._test = 2; // compiled OK

    B bb(a);
    bb._test = 2; // compilation error
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain me what causes such behaviour?

I'm using XCode 7.0, LLVM 7.0 default compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: because `const add_lvalue_reference_t<int>` is `int&`.

Comment: In `const int&`, it's `int` that's const, not reference. It's a reference to `const int`, not "a const reference to `int`". But in `cons T`, it's `T` that's `const`, not some sub-type of `T`. When `T` is a reference type, `const T` means "const reference" - but that's a no-op; references are, in a sense, always `const` (you can't change what it refers to, once initialized).

Comment: Another way to look at it: if `T` were `int*`, `const T` would be `int* const` (a const pointer to non-const `int`), which is not at all the same as `const int*` aka `int const*` (a non-const pointer to const `int`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Answers should be posted in the big textarea below!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the language standard.

> N4140 §8.3.2 [dcl.ref]/1
>
> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or
>   *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef int& A;
> const A aref = 3; // ill-formed; lvalue reference to non-const initialized with rvalue
> ```
>
> The type of `aref` is “lvalue reference to `int`”, not “lvalue
>   reference to `const int`”. —*end example* ]